# Debugging a views_json view that shows data when logged in and is empty when logged out

Tags: 7, views

OK, first the problem, then the setup:

## The Problem

I have a taxonomy view that returns json containing data about nodes that are associated with a taxonomy term.  When I am logged in with any role, the view shows data.  When I am not logged in the json is empty.

## The Setup

I have a taxonomy view that returns json containing data about nodes that are associated with a taxonomy term.  The paths are json_file/%/en and json_file/%/ja depending on the language the query is made in.  There are then filters checking content type, language, and the state of a couple of file upload fields as well as a filter checking that the content is published.  Access control is set to Role with all roles including anonymous user checked.  Contextual filters are Content: Has taxonomy ID (with depth) and Content: Has Taxonomy term ID depth modifier.

In practice the url ends up looking like /json_file/climate/en because in `MYMODULE_views_pre_view` I look up the tid based on the value in the url and replace the argument.  I have confirmed that it is properly getting the tid.

So between the Access settings including anonymous users, the filter not containing anything to prevent anonymous users from seeing the data, and there being nothing related to the issue in the contextual filters, I'm wondering what else I can do to debug this? What might cause a view to have no result when a user is not logged in?

## I've tried:

- I've tried changing the Access control to None and clearing cache.
- I've removed the content published filter and cleared the cache.
- I've removed all caching that I could find from the view and cleared the cache.

Comment: did you clear the cache? maybe change access from role to none.

Comment: OK, I set access to None, and cleared cache, still no results when I'm not logged in.

Comment: I also turned off Caching on the view and cleared cache again to be sure.  Still no joy.

Comment: Is there any way to make views log the queries it runs temporarily? It is hard to get a send of what stage things are going wrong at.

Comment: I started removing things until it started showing data and removing a relationship to file contents did it.  Now to put everything else back and see if it still works.  Not sure how I can filter the way I want without being able to load the contents of that field.

Comment: maybe its a permission thing, anonymous needs some sort of permission for file contents. Check people >> permissions.

Comment: You are probably right.  It would be nice if watchdog gave me any useful information about what was being denied because I can't see any reason why I should be able to view and download the files in the node page, but that a relationship to the file field should cause the view to break.  I'll do some more thinking on it today, but I may just drop the checks (this was to make sure that if there wasn't a cover image, the file was a pdf so I could generate one) and display a placeholder if no cover image comes through in JSON.

Comment: In the end, I just removed the relationship, I think the debugging steps were: 1) backup the view as it is now, 2)  turn off access control, 3)clear the cache, 4) turn off views caching, 5) clear the cache, start a loop of removing one thing, saving, clearing cache, and testing the view until removing one thing makes the view work 6) restore the view from backup, 7) remove that one thing or figure out how to make that one thing work.  If that is worth an answer for future googlers, and you'd care to write it up, I'd be glad to accept it.  Otherwise I can close the question.

Comment: Just wondering, what relationship where you using?

Comment: It was a relationship for file contents.  I used that to filter for mimetype to load only nodes with the cover image present or the first public file being a pdf so I could generate a fallback cover.

Comment: My best guess is that is https://www.drupal.org/node/2113919 or a similar bug causing the issue.  I've had to remove the same relationship in some other views too.

Comment: looks like that's probably it.